# ReactJS -- Child props not updating/rerendering when parent state updated

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rendering, state

**In a nutshell:**
I'm making a web page to streamline a game I play with my middle school students sometimes. I'm using one stateful React component to pass props to a child. The problem is that the child's props do not update/rerender when the parent's state is updated. I've looked at several questions/answers here, but none seem to quite match my problem. I've also made several other webpages with the same setup and have never had this problem. I even went back and compared this code to some of my other "successful" projects, and can't figure out what it is about this that's different/making it not work.

**More specifically:** I'm working on making a scoreboard that lists what yardline each team is on, what their score is, and a menu of buttons for actions the team can take. One such action is to "gain 10 yards." There is currently a button tied to the function "gain10" for the parent component "Scoreboard". It adds 10 to the team's yard stat, and will eventually move their football avatar 10 yards. I noticed at some point that while it properly updates the state of the parent Scoreboard, the yard stat does not change in the rendering. The button/gain10 function also changes the "turn" piece of the team's state, which should disable the button, but it does not. It seems to me that the parent is passing down the initial props as set up in the constructor, and not re-rendering after `setState()` is called in `gain10()` to update them. They *are* being updated, though.

The code is admittedly messy because a) I'm but a humble math teacher who informally learned to code on their own, and b) it's a mixture of what I originally tried to do (pass the entire team object from the state then pick it apart when creating the child component) vs. passing information directly from the state when rendering. I could go on about the wonkiness you may see in this code, but let's just get to it:

```
class Scoreboard extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      team1: {
        num: 1,
        yards: 10,
        score: 0,
        hasBall: true,
        turn: true,
        css: "top",
        ball: 'https://i.ibb.co/6n6bt0Y/football1.png',
        class: 'v-fb',
        style: {top: 2 + "em", left: 26.5 + "em"}
      },
      team2: {
        num: 2,
        yards: 20,
        score: 10,
        hasBall: true,
        turn: false,
        css: "top",
        ball: 'https://i.ibb.co/ngfTbLW/football2.png',
        class: 'v-fb',
        style: {top: 42.5 +"em", left: 21.5 + "em"}
      },
      team3: {
        num: 3,
        yards: 10,
        score: 0,
        hasBall: true,
        turn: false,
        css: "left",
        ball: 'https://i.ibb.co/vvWSCYW/football3.png',
        class: 'h-fb',
        style: {top: 42.5 +"em", left: 21.5 + "em"}
      },
      team4: {
        num: 4,
        yards: 10,
        score: 0,
        hasBall: true,
        turn: false,
        css: "left",
        ball: 'https://i.ibb.co/vDXmqb5/football4.png',
        class: 'h-fb',
        style: {top: 42.5 +"em", left: 21.5 + "em"}
      }
    }
    this.gain10 = this.gain10.bind(this)
  }

  gain10(e) {
    var id = e.target.id
    console.log(this.state.team1)
    this.setState((state) => {
      state[id].yards += 10
      state[id].turn = !state[id].turn
    })
  }

  render() {
    return(
      <div id="scoerboard">
        <TeamBoard team="team1" 
          yards = {this.state.team1.yards}
          score = {this.state.team1.score}
          turn = {this.state.team1.turn}
          teamData = {this.state.team1}
          func={this.gain10}/>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

const TeamBoard = (props) => {
  var id = `${props.team}-board`
  return (
    <div id={id}>
      <img src={props.teamData.ball} class={props.teamData.class} style={props.teamData.style}/>
      <p>team {props.teamData.num} stats</p>
      <p>
        <span class="board-label">Yards:</span> {props.yards}
        <span class="board-label">Score:</span> {props.score}
      </p>
      <button id={props.team} onClick={props.func} disabled={!props.turn}>go</button>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Entire code (oh dear) and visual can be seen on [this pen](https://codepen.io/Klammyq/pen/VwYKgXX), though it's actively being changed to continue trying to figure this out...

Comment: There are 2 issues with your call to setState. The first (and simplest) is that your function does not return anything. The second, more nuanced, issue is that state changes are only tracked one level deep. When you change the value of `team1.yards`, the team1 object has not changed, so no re-render is triggered. You should return a new object with the updated values. Something like `return {[id]: { ...state[id], yards: state[id].yards+10, turn: !state[id].turn }}` should fix both problems.

Comment: Thank you so much, it indeed fixed both problems! I have a question (or two or three) about your code, if you'd care to elaborate. What does the "..." do before state[id]? Is it something like defining which key in the state is changing, followed by which keys in that particular object are changing? And this avoids overwriting the entire 'team' object and losing the keys/values that aren't being updated?

Comment: You should read this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax. The premise is that you're creating a new object that is a copy of the old object (i.e., contains the same key/value pairs), then updating the `yards` and `turn` properties to their new values.